# Spring Boot - TestRestTemplate - @ExceptionHandler method invoked 2 times for 401 response status

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate, spring-boot-test

I have @ExceptionHandler inside a @ControllerAdvice which returns response with UNAUTHORIZED status.
I recently switched to Spring Boot 3.0.2, which caused some ITs to fail. During investigation of one of those ITs, I noticed that this handler method is invoked 2 times. This occurs only in this test - doesn't happen when request is sent from Postman. Also, other exception handlers aren't invoked multiple times, so I guess it has something to do with 401 status.

Spring Boot 3.0.2 (happens with 2.7.3)

Exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(UNAUTHORIZED)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUnauthorizedException(UnauthorizedException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(UNAUTHORIZED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(OtherException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleOtherException(OtherException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorResponse);
    }

}
```

TestRestTemplate call:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

...

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(SESSION_ID_HEADER, sessionId);
ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
    path,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new HttpEntity<>(request, headers),
    ErrorResponse.class);
```

Is this expected behaviour and can I somehow disable this retry mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

It depends on what HttpClient you are using, but for me the problem came from within Apache HttpClient.

Between Spring 2.x and 3.x the Apache HttpClient version has been bumped as well from 4.x to 5.x,and the latest version has new default behaviour for request retries.

I was able to fix the problem in my application by adding the configuration

```
@Autowired
public void configureTestRestTemplate(TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate, HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.disableAutomaticRetries().build();

    testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
}
```

inside my TestApplication @SpringBootApplication class.

In my case [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy.html) was the offending class.